# How to remove class with ng-mouseenter in this case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-class

On the `div` with the class of `ticker`, I'd like to remove the `pulse` CSS animation class once the user `ng-mouseenter`s.

I don't have a directive setup just for the `ticker` div, but is there a simple way to remove or update the `pulse` class in this case?

Markup

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tik in tgh.tag.tickers">
        <div class="tag-container" ng-mouseleave="tgh.leaveAssoTicker(tik)">
            <div class="ticker"
                 ng-class="{'fade-1 pulse' : tgh.tag.mainSearch}"
                 ng-mouseenter="tgh.hoverAssoTicker(tik)"
                 ng-click="tgh.selectTicker(tik)">{{tik.ticker}}</div>
            <ticker-hover ticker="tik"></ticker-hover>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The mouseenter function

```
function hoverAssoTicker(ticker, type) {
    vs.tickerTagsHoverTimeout = $timeout(function() {

        var theTicker = {};

        if (ticker.ticker === undefined) {
            theTicker.ticker = ticker;
        } else {
            theTicker.ticker = ticker.ticker;
        }

        ApiFactory.getTickerDetails(theTicker.ticker).then(function(data) {

            ticker.longname = data.data.tickers[0].longname;

            if (type === 'portfolio') {
                ticker.removePortfolio = true;
            }
            else if (type === 'searched') {
                ticker.addPortfolio = true;
            }
            else {
               ticker.removePortfolio = false,
               ticker.addPortfolio    = false;
            }

            ticker.tickerHoverDisplay = true;
        });

        vs.closeTagsTikHoverTimer = $timeout(function() {
            if (ticker.tickerHoverDisplay) ticker.tickerHoverDisplay = false;
        }, 2000);

        $rootScope.$broadcast(vs.closeTagsTikHoverTimer);
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a binding variable and use that in `ng-class`, such as `ticker.isMouseover`. Then in your `ng-mouseenter` event, set it to true, and vice versa for `ng-mouseleave`.

Then you can have something like `ng-class="{pulse: !tik.isMouseover}"`

Comment: Nice, ok.. but then how would you combine that with `tgh.tag.mainSearch` which is what `pulse` needs to show up in the first place.

Comment: Just combine them both into an expression. If `pulse` should only be available when both `tgh.tag.mainSearch` and you're not over the ticker, then just have: `pulse: tgh.tag.mainSearch && !tik.isMouseover`